# Proving a different version of MVT

Tags: real-analysis

$f(x)$ is differentiable in $[a,b]$, $f'(a) = f'(b) = 0$,
Prove $\exists c \in (a,b)$ such that $f(c)-f(a) = (c-a)f'(c)$

What i have tried:
$f(x)$ is differentiable in $[a,b]$ imply $f(x)$ is continuous in $[a,b]$

so we can use MVT, we get
 $f(b)-f(a) = (b-a)f'(\zeta_1) $ for some $\zeta_1$ in  $(a,b)$
 $f(c)-f(a) = (c-a)f'(\zeta_2) $ for some $\zeta_2$ in  $(a,c)$

I can't figure out how to use the condition $f'(a) = f'(b) = 0$

Comment: Some first steps:

If $f$ is constant, the statement holds with $c=(b-a)/2$, so we assume $f$ is not constant.

We may assume without loss of generality that $f'(x) \ne 0$ for all $x \in (a,b)$, i.e., $f$ is strictly monotonic in $[a,b]$. (Do you see why?)

After this, I am stuck because the solutions I am considering rely on the continuity of the derivative... hopefully someone can help you out.

Answer (score 3):

Put $\displaystyle g(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$, with $g(a)=f^{\prime}(a)=0$. We compute : $\displaystyle g^{\prime}(x)=\frac{(x-a)f^{\prime}(x)-(f(x)-f(a))}{(x-a)^2}$. Now suppose that the assertion is false. Then $g^{\prime}(x)$ is not zero for $x\in (a,b)$. By Darboux's theorem, $g^{\prime}$ has a constant sign on $(a,b)$. Suppose for example that $g^{\prime}(x)>0$. We have  that $g$ is strictly increasing on $(a,b)$. Hence  $g(b)>g(a)=0$ and $f(b)-f(a)>0$. Now as $g$ is increasing, we have $g^{\prime}(b)\geq 0$, hence $(b-a)f^{\prime}(b)-(f(b)-f(a))\geq 0$ and as $f^{\prime}(b)=0$, $0\geq f(b)-f(a)$, a contradiction. Same proof if we suppose $g^{\prime}(x)<0$ on $(a,b)$.

Comment: Very nice proof indeed! +1